# Consume SOAP web service with Angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rest, web-services

I know that We can consume `Restful services` within our `Angular` apps. But one of my client gave me a `web service` like so `http://123.618.196.10/WCFTicket/Service1.svc?wsdl`. So my question is can I use this within an `Angular` app? I have never used it. Any clue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[ngx-soap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-soap)** is a great library which I have used in our one of the client project.

Here are steps to use this library.

**Step 1:**  install ngx-soap and dependencies

```
npm install --save ngx-soap

npm install --save buffer concat-stream core-js crypto-js events lodash sax stream uuid
```

**Step 2:**

```
import { NgxSoapModule } from 'ngx-soap';
...
    @NgModule({
        imports: [ ..., NgxSoapModule, ... ]
    ...
```

**Step 3:** Inject NgxSoapService in your component

```
...
import { NgxSoapService, Client, ISoapMethodResponse } from 'ngx-soap';
...

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    client: Client;

    constructor(private soap: NgxSoapService) {
        this.soap.createClient('http://123.618.196.10/WCFTicket/Service1.svc?wsdl').subscribe(client => this.client = client);
    }
 }
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Nice to have a guy who has used it. Are you happy about the performance of this conversion? Because this is for a mobile app.

Comment: Don't you have any idea about the performance of the service after this kind of wrapper?

Comment: I used for web application and I don't see any performance issue. For mobile, there might be a performance issue.

Comment: Thanks. One more question. Can you tell me a tool to see the details of this kind of `WSDL` service? When I opened it on a browser the details are no clear. i.e. exposed method `names`, `parameters` and etc. e.g. http://www.thomas-bayer.com/axis2/services/BLZService?wsdl

Comment: you can use SOAPUI maybe ?

Comment: ngx-soap is outdated and abandoned. last supported with Angular 10, doesn't work with Angular 11+